# making a dropdownlist or a simple picker with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't want to transfer all of my data list to view, I have research in most of examples they are transfer whole of list to view I need something to load with paging, my problem is my list is kind of heavy list so how I can make a simple picker like a dropdownlist but with paging mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am used for this porposes [flexbox](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox) in my projects.